# 2 разных файла как запустить?

Tags: python

Есть основной файл и дополнительный. Как запустить дополнительный файл из основного?

Comment: Что значит запустить файл?

Comment: Просто импортировать? При импорте исполняется весь код файла (если мы о `Python` говорим).

Comment: Чтобы команды из доп файла работали в первом файле. Так можно?

Comment: @Onebet, вполне реально. Но я бы вам посоветовал сделать 3 файла. 2 - основной код и 1 - код для объединения двух первых и описания их поведения(что, как и при каких условиях запускается). Тогда вам надо просто использовать последний файл для работы всего кода(запускаете последний файл и все должно работать).

Comment: @DGDays Я понимаю, что это реально. Вопрос в том, что надо написать, чтобы оно работало.

Answer (score 0):

При импорте "дополнительного" файла из основного, будет исполняться весь код "дополнительного" который исполнился бы если файл был бы запущен отдельно. К функциям и классам дополнительного .py файла можно обращаться через точку.
Чтобы понять как работают импорты можете поискать материалы в Google по запросу "импорты в python", проблем возникнуть не должно.